# How can I add OR relationship in laravel middleware for a Route

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-permission

I'm using [spatie/laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) to add permissions for my routes.

One of the routes I have can be accessed by two permissions (`earnings`, `financial_fund`). The user doesn't need to have both permissions to access the controller. He can access the controller by having one of the permissions or both of them.

I've tried to write something like this.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['can:earnings']], function () {
    Route::get('/payment', [PaymentsController::class, 'getAll']);
    Route::post('/payment/cash', [PaymentsController::class, 'addCashPayment']);
});
Route::group(['middleware' => ['can:financial_fund']], function () {
    Route::get('/payment', [PaymentsController::class, 'getAll']);
    Route::post('/payment/cash', [PaymentsController::class, 'addCashPayment']);
});
```

But the above code allows only users with `can:earnings` permission to access the routes, it doesn't allow users with `can:financial_fund` permission.

I've also tried to write something like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['can:earnings,financial_fund']], function () {
    Route::get('/payment', [PaymentsController::class, 'getAll']);
    Route::post('/payment/cash', [PaymentsController::class, 'addCashPayment']);
});
```

But this requires both of permissions to exist with the current user.

How can I tell that I want only one of the permissions at least to exist?

I have found that Laravel has introduced the `canAny` for use in blade templates. Is there a way I can use it in my api.php file while defining the Routes?

Comment: Just use OR operator.```['can:earnings|financial_fund']```.Routes are always executed from top to bottom . So once it receive the relevant route it will not execute further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by creating a new middleware

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthorizeCanAny
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$permissions)
    {
        if (!$request->user()) {
            abort(403);
        }

        $userPermissions = array_map(function ($e) {
            return $e['name'];
        }, $request->user()->permissions->toArray());

        $userPermissionsIntersect = array_intersect($userPermissions, $permissions);

        if (!sizeof($userPermissionsIntersect)) {
            abort(403);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Adding the middleware to kernal.php file

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...,
    'canAny' => AuthorizeCanAny::class,
];
```

Then use it in the router

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['canAny:earnings,financial_fund']], function () {
    Route::get('/payment', [PaymentsController::class, 'getAll']);
    Route::post('/payment/cash', [PaymentsController::class, 'addCashPayment']);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way — create new class that extend Authorize middleware and override in method handle **authorize** to **any**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize;

class CanAny extends Authorize
{
    #[\Override]
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $ability, ...$models)
    {
        $this->gate->any($ability, $this->getGateArguments($request, $models));

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Add this to Kernel class

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...,
    'can.any' => \App\Http\Middleware\CanAny::class,
];
```

Now you can use it in routes

```
Route::resource('posts', PostController::class)->middleware('can.any:post,read);
```

Comment: Reminder: Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools are not allowed on Stack Overflow. [Learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).